# Delegate method signature with object and value assignment

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to make an IEnumerable extension similar to one shown in [Using LINQ's Zip with a closure that doesn't return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190324/using-linqs-zip-with-a-closure-that-doesnt-return-a-value) by @Hakakou, however I'm trying to modify it to run a method of the first value, with the second value as parameter.

For example:

```
public class MyObject {

  private int myInt;

  public MyObject(int a){
    myInt = a;
  }

  public void addToFloat(int b){
    myInt += b;
  }

}

List<MyObject> objList = new List<ObjList> {new MyObj(5), new MyObj(8)};
List<int> intList = new List<int> {3, 1};

objList.MyExtension(intList, addToFloat)

// Now both MyObjects should have myInt set to 8 and 9 respectively
```

I'm not however sure how to 'separate' a method from the object and save its signature, then be able to apply it for each object instance with a given value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to create a new *linq-style* method extension, I think you have to use this code:

```
static class MyExtensionClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<TObj> MyExtension<TObj, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TObj> listObject, IEnumerable<TValue> listValue, Action<TObj, TValue> fun)
    {
        if (listObjectis null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(listObject));
        if (listValue is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(listValue));
        if (fun is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fun));
    
        using var enumerator = listValue.GetEnumerator();
        foreach (var obj in listObject)
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                fun(obj, enumerator.Current);
            yield return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

But, there are some warnings:

1. the assumption is that if the listValue contains less values than listObject, only the first couples will be pass in the function;
2. the linq system is easy to use but not good for performance, so if you don't need to use this extension method in a linq chain the best chois is to use a simple void method without yield.

in fact I have not use the ".Count()" method (for exemple to check if the two list have the same lenght), because in the worst case it will force the evaluation of all item.

Tip: if you are using .NET 6, for the [null checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull?view=net-6.0#System_ArgumentNullException_ThrowIfNull_System_Object_System_String_) you can use

```
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(listObject);
```

instead of explicit if and throw